# Creating a new user with SSH access on ec2

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to add a new user to an EC2 instance and giving that user SSH access. (RHEL 6.5)

I do this by copying the content of .ssh from the default ec2-user's home dir to the new user's home dir. I change the ownership of the dir and the content so that the new user is the owner.

However when I try to SSH into the machine with the new user, I get "access denied"

```
ssh -i my.pem new-user@<ip>
```

while

```
ssh -i my.pem ec2-user@<ip>
```

still works

(I have set a password for the new user, and there is no white/black list in the ssh config file)

Am I failing to see the consepts of ssh and keypairs here or is this a ec2 related thing?

Comment: server logs would be helpful. It should be in `/var/log/secure` and should tell you more about the reason of the failure.